# Android: How to open a specific calendar event with its ID

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a recyclerview which displays the events of the calendar, I want that when I click on an event it opens the event in the calendar

Comment: set onClickListener on your itemView. But would be very nice if you show some code, becouse this question have no sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you looking for is [Calendar intent](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/intents-of-androids-calendar-app/) here is tutorials.